# setuptools seems to find incorrect match

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm new to python and hitting issues trying to use setuptools (which seems to be the recommended way to get dependencies for CI).

Following (amongst other guides) these:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/distribute/
https://pytest.org/latest/goodpractises.html#integration-with-setuptools-test-commands

my setup.py says:

```
install_requires=['Flask','Flask-SQLAlchemy'],
```

However when I run "setup.py test" Flask-SQLAlchemy is installed and fails:

```
(.venv)root@apb:/projectmanager# ./setup.py test
running test
Searching for Flask-SQLAlchemy
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/Flask-SQLAlchemy/ 
Best match: Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/F/Flask-SQLAlchemy/Flask-SQLAlchemy-2.0.tar.gz#md5=06ae73194cca73b72e178f870d1dac7c
Processing Flask-SQLAlchemy-2.0.tar.gz
...
Installed /projectmanager/Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.0-py2.7.egg
Searching for Flask
Best match: Flask SQLAlchemy-2.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/F/Flask-SQLAlchemy/Flask-SQLAlchemy-2.0.tar.gz#md5=06ae73194cca73b72e178f870d1dac7c
Processing Flask-SQLAlchemy-2.0.tar.gz
...
Installed /projectmanager/Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.0-py2.7.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./setup.py", line 135, in <module>
    cmdclass = {'test': PyTest},
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/projectmanager/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/test.py", line 132, in run
    self.distribution.install_requires)
  File "/projectmanager/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 287, in fetch_build_eggs
    replace_conflicting=True,
  File "/projectmanager/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 639, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Flask
```

I don't understand why it's:
a) processing the dependencies out of order
b) not finding Flask

As this is really an app rather than a library, using pip and requirements.txt is an option, however I like the standardisation setuptools brings.

Update: specifying 'Flask>=0.10.1' cures the problem - but why? There is no version of flask anywhere on the system.

Many thanks